# Facebook Like Button Code won't work in HTML Email

Tags: html, facebook, email, facebook-like

I am trying to add the like button code into a html newsletter but it won't display, only displays on the online version. Is it possible to have it display in the email newsletter as well, if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

No this is not possible.  The best you can do is a static like button image that takes you to your fan page or website where they can then click on a real like button.  You can't embed scripts into email and have them execute, which is required to convert the like button code into the necessary rendered iframe.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using the 'like button' is using the html only share button. Technically its not supported, but hey it works.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://mylink.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use javascript directly on emails.

But you can put a button/link to a page of your own, whose purpose is to hold the actual like button.